# terminating a monadic fold early

Tags: haskell, monads, fold

I've written this so that I can terminate a monadic fold early:

```
myfoldM             :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m (Maybe a)) -> a -> [b] -> m (Maybe a)
myfoldM _ a []      =  return $ Just a
myfoldM f a (x:xs)  =  do ma <- f a x;
                          case ma of
                            Nothing -> return Nothing
                            Just a' -> myfoldM f a' xs
```

and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to express this or if something similar exists in a library. Of course there is an analogous version replacing `Maybe` with `Either`.

Update... here is a complete solution based on Petr Pudlák's answer:

```
import Control.Monad (foldM,Monad,mzero)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

myfoldM' :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> MaybeT m a) -> a -> [b] -> m (Maybe a)
myfoldM' f = (runMaybeT .) . foldM f

go :: Int -> Int -> MaybeT IO Int
go s i = do
  lift $ putStrLn $ "i = " ++ show i
  if i <= 4 then return (s+i) else mzero

test n = do
  myfoldM' go 0 [1..n] >>= print      

-- test 3 => Just 6
-- test 5 => Nothing
```

Comment: Don't write your own fold, wrap your function so that it works with the standard fold.

Comment: essentially that's the question I'm asking - could you give me an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just a standard monadic [`foldM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM) enhanced with early exit. This can be done just by wrapping the inner computation into [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#t:MaybeT):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Error
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

myfoldM :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m (Maybe a)) -> a -> [b] -> m (Maybe a)
myfoldM f = (runMaybeT .) . foldM ((MaybeT .) . f)
```

But I'd say it's more convenient for the folding function to be given using `MaybeT` directly, because then it can easily terminate the computation by [`mzero`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mzero), instead of manipulating `Maybe` values, and in such a case it's almost not worth writing a separate function for it:

```
myfoldM' :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> MaybeT m a) -> a -> [b] -> m (Maybe a)
myfoldM' f = (runMaybeT .) . foldM f
```

For `Either` it's the same:

```
myfoldM'' :: (Monad m, Error e)
          => (a -> b -> ErrorT e m a) -> a -> [b] -> m (Either e a)
myfoldM'' f = (runErrorT .) . foldM f
```

Comment: Might be a little easier to read in pointful form:

``myfoldM f e l = runMaybeT (foldM (\ i o -> (MaybeT) (f i o)) e l)``